# Custom page with panels in two languages

Tags: panels, i18n-l10n

I created two pages with panels in Drupal 7; they have different names and different languages, but only one can be active as home page.

Comment: You don't actually have a question up there. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can only have one page as the front page, which I assume is what you want. The way to do this, is using a "Selection rule" on language, and two variants, not two pages.

See [Learn Page manager](http://dev.nodeone.se/en/learn-page-manager) for a deeper introduction to Page manager.